# Should calls to a public shared functions be locked for thread safety

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

As in the title. Should be calls to public shared functions be locked for thread safety ?

Comment: Related: [Are non-synchronised static methods thread safe if they don't modify static class variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173399)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if your public shared libraries use class level variables and no if they use local variables.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is a component or bean and runs on multi thread environment like tomcat server then the function (object) must be locked if it writes data in shared memory

Answer (score 0):

No.

Firstly, they may not even need locking.

Secondly, if the users of your function aren't multithreaded, then you pay the locking overhead for no benefit.

You should clearly document whether the function is thread-safe or not, and allow the users to make the decision. For a Java example, see the collections framework.