# What is shared state , race condition when it occurs?

Tags: java, thread-safety

```
    //$Id$    
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ThreadSafe {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ThreadSafe.class.getName());

    public static int  random(int num){
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"Entered Num : {0}",num);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"Interrupted Exception");
        }
        return num + 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int threads=1;threads<100;threads++){
            final int number = threads;
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int val = ThreadSafe.random(number);
                    System.out.println("Excepted Value = " + (number+2) + " Returned Value = " + val);
                }

            },"Thread : "+threads);
            thread.start();
        }
    }


}
```

Output:

```
30 Jan, 2013 11:41:26 PM com.zoho.learn.test.ThreadSafe random
INFO: Entered Num : 2
30 Jan, 2013 11:41:26 PM com.zoho.learn.test.ThreadSafe random
INFO: Entered Num : 45
30 Jan, 2013 11:41:26 PM com.zoho.learn.test.ThreadSafe random
INFO: Entered Num : 44
30 Jan, 2013 11:41:26 PM com.zoho.learn.test.ThreadSafe random
INFO: Entered Num : 43
30 Jan, 2013 11:41:26 PM com.zoho.learn.test.ThreadSafe random
INFO: Entered Num : 42
30 Jan, 2013 11:41:26 PM com.zoho.learn.test.ThreadSafe random
INFO: Entered Num : 38
Excepted Value = 47 Returned Value = 47
30 Jan, 2013 11:41:26 PM com.zoho.learn.test.ThreadSafe random
INFO: Entered Num : 41
Excepted Value = 44 Returned Value = 44
Excepted Value = 46 Returned Value = 46
```

I am excepting multi threads accessing a same method at same time. What happens if we access a static methods at same time?

When race condition occurs?

What is shared-state?

Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: What output were you expecting, and why?

Comment: Why do you think it would cause a race condition ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth , Sorry for the Incoherent post. I edited my points . 

Thank you

Comment: @BaptisteWicht , I assumed If multi threads accessing a same method at same time the race condition will occurs. Is it wrong?

Comment: @bharathi Yes it is wrong, race condition only occurs when there is a shared resource. Access to a method is never a problem, the problem is executing code in parallel on shared resources. The answer of Tomasz Nurkiewicz explains well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only piece of code (except `run()`) executed concurrently is:

```
public static int  random(int num){
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"Entered Num : {0}",num);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"Interrupted Exception");
    }
    return num + 2;
}
```

Stripping logging (which is thread-safe in every sane implementation), sleeping (which only affects current thread) and exception handling, this is what you are left with:

```
public static int  random(int num){
    return num + 2;
}
```

Not only `num` argument is private to each thread (each thread has its own stack memory), but also it's never modified. Thus, race condition cannot occur in your program.

There is no shared state (global variables) in your code, race condition is only possible when one thread modifies shared data while other reads it.

You want to see a race condition? Here you go!

```
private volatile int globalNum;

public static int  random(int num){
    globalNum = num;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"Interrupted Exception");
    }
    return globalNum + 2;
}
```

Last seconds from disaster:

1. Thread 1 enters `random(42)`, assigning `globalNum = 42` and goes to sleep
2. Thread 2 enters `random(17)`, assigning `globalNum = 17` and goes to sleep
3. Thread 1 wakes up reads current value of `globalNum` (which is `17`) and returns `19` instead of `44` as expected.

## See also

- [Are non-synchronised static methods thread safe if they don't modify static class variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173399)

Answer (score 0):

> I am excepting multi threads accessing a same method at same time.

Multiple threads accessing the same method is not a problem.  A race condition can only exist if multiple threads access the same **state**.  You have no shared state in your program, so there is no race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Multi threading becomes critical when they access a common resource.
This can be a static variable which one thread changes while the other one reads.

Local variables are not affected, neither method calls, because each thread has ist own local variables.

You dont have common resources shared between the treads.