# Java Passing ArrayList to another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe

Hi I am learning java and in my project I am trying to pass a data to another JFrame.

This is my Guest Frame class

```
public class GuestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public GuestFrame(){
         initComponents();             
    }
}
```

The way I am adding data to arraylist is by adding selected item from JList to the cart appended one by one like so :

```
private void kButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    String receiveList = lstEntitety.getSelectedValue().toString(); 
    list.add(receiveList); 
    //System.out.println(list.toString()); outputs all the data added
```

And the getter function for that list :

```
public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
}
```

What I am trying to do is display all the added food in my another JFrame

```
public class CartFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private GuestFrame food;
     public CartFrame() {     
     initComponents();
     food= new GuestFrame();
     List<String> list = food.getList();

     //Here I am trying to output the arraylist that I appended in prevous frame
     jTextArea1.setText(list.toString());

}
```

---

The result upon stepping into CartFrame is that array seems to output empty []

I figured it might be because in Guest frame constructor is overriding it ?

I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Initialize `ArrayList` at the time of declaration `private List<String> list ==new ArrayList<String>(); ` remove from constructor

Comment: I tried that but the result is still empty array

Comment: at which point this method is called `kButton1ActionPerformed`? and try to print all objects added to arraylist in that method and check once

Comment: when appending the items to cart, from the GuestFrame class. After that the items should be displayed in CartFrame but the result is empty. The printouts are outputing the right results appended one by one.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) Don't extend components or windows unless there is a good reason to do so. I see none here. 4) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Thanks Andrew I will take your advices.

Comment: *"Thanks Andrew I will take your advices."* Tip: Add @Deadpool (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. I realize you weren't replying to Deadpool in this case, but it was only chance that allowed me to see your comment. BTW - please let me know when you've made the edit to add an MCVE / SSCCE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried my best to make it minimal and understandable as I can , and I removed all the code I think is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Have you read both links on the MCVE & SSCCE? IT is not ***all*** about making code minimal or short. Also note that na MCVE / SSCCE can be up to 200 lines of code if it is all truly relevant to the problem, or displaying it on screen (e.g. imports, a `main` method etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 3 options to solve this case, 
1. may use database to manipulate the list data. so `GuestFrame` is used to save data while `CartFrame` can get the data from database without have dependency on other class property. 
2. second, may use [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to manipulate list data.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("xyz.properties");
prop.load(in);
```

save data in `GuestFrame`:

```
prop.setProperty("dataSize", "(list.lenght())");
prop.setProperty("data1", "...");
prop.setProperty("data2", "...");
prop.setProperty("...", "...");
....
prop.store(new FileOutputStream("xyz.properties"), null);
```

load data in `CartFrame`:

```
prop.getProperty("dataSize");
//loop i=0 until < dataSize
list.add(prop.getProperty("data"+i));
```

3. last option is to make `private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` become static `private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`, so then other classes can access the list property from `GuestFrame` directly without need to create the instance.

```
  public class GuestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public GuestFrame(){
       initComponents();    

    }

    public static List<String> getList() {
       return list;
    }
 }
```

```
 public class CartFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 public CartFrame() {     
   initComponents();
   List<String> list = GuestFrame.getList();
   cText.setText(list.toString());
   jLabel3.setText(list.toString());
 }
}
```

**Static** property are associated to the class directly. they can be called even without creating an instance of the class, ex: ClassName.propertyName

Comment: btw you can also change `private static` into `public static` so then in the `CarFrame` can get the list value by accessing `GuessFrame` property directly `List<String> list = GuestFrame.list;` so that doesnt need to create `getList()` method

Comment: Well yeah It works this way. I am fairly new but while searching for the answer I saw a lot of answers explicitly saying that static should not be used when doing this kind of task, mainly because of OOP ways and security..?

Comment: *"I think one of the option is to make .. become static"* It might be an option, but it is a terrible one. Using `static` to make members of one class visible to another is bad design, and more often **leads** to problems, than **solves** them.

Comment: yeah I know, I offer this option because I thought it is only a simple case.
than for more safer, may save data into the database. so  `GuestFrame` is used to save data while inside `CartFrame` can get the data from database without have dependency on other class property.

Comment: or can save/load data using `properties` file, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: But in this example I don't want to save to database until the final step, after the "checkout" , to save the orders into the database, because I want to further manipulate the data in the cart, for example removing item etc...

Comment: then may use static, static is thread-safe 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173399/are-non-synchronised-static-methods-thread-safe-if-they-dont-modify-static-clas

Comment: or as I commented earlier may use properties file to keep and load the data

Comment: @MFauzanAbdi Thank you for your time, the properties file saving and loading does seems like an promising approach to try on this...

Comment: Thank you, do you know what would be a general idea or approach to do this with implementing an interface for the CartFrame?